# Open text file and slice words based on blank spaces

Tags: python, file

I want to open text file and slice words based on blank spaces, but cut by `\n`. Why does it work like this? Is the problem in the text file or that my code is wrong?

```py
def process(w):
    output =""
    for ch in w:
        if ch.isalpha() :
            output += ch
    return output.lower()

words = set()
fname = input("file name: ")
file = open(fname, "r")
for line in file:
    lineWords = line.split()
    for word in lineWords:
        words.add(process(lineWords))

print("Number of words used =", len(words))

print(words)
```

Text file:

[image: text file]

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: There is issue in your code, could you please share your expected output

Comment: If I am able to understand the question correctly,  changing <<words.add(process(word))>> will work.  but its better to use nltk for this